# Windows Automatic Multiple User login command line

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, authentication

I am trying to have a windows Admin account automatically login multiple local users on a script.  The idea is to run a set of applications (tests) in each user session.
Currently I am able to do so by loggin in remotely (RDC) to each of the individual user accounts.  This would be fine if there were just a few of these accounts, but now I have upwards of 30 machines with an average of 6 user accounts each so RDPing to each is extremely time consuming.
Instead, I'd like to be able to login as the Admin, and have some sort of script to automatically login the local users within a group, or just a list of users, so I can start the applications using pstools  (the applications require desktop interaction, so a session is required).
I have found that you can only automatically login one user via Windows User Accounts.

Does anyone know of a way to login multiple accounts via command line, or automatically somehow?

Comment: Something's a bit unclear: when you say "the applications require desktop interaction", do you mean that you have to manually interact with each application?

Comment: The application itself interacts with the user session (taking screenshots, saving user specific files, etc).  What I meant by desktop interaction is that the application needs a user session to run (instead of /runas context)

Comment: Which flavor of Windows are we talking about? XP? 7? 8? In any case, the only means I know to perform this task would be to use windows autologon. I don't know of any means to programmatically logon/logoff several users in a row. If someone else does, though, I'm interested as well :)

Comment: Specifically Server 2008, but if there are any solutions for Win7/8 I would be happy to know.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Invoke-Command` to execute commands against a remote computer which also has Powershell, and has WinRM enabled.  `Invoke-Command` can also run non-Powershell commands.

```
# users stored in csv with "username, password" format
foreach ($user in $userlist) {
    Invoke-Command "runas /profile /credentials $creds /user:$user.username /password:$user.password *executable*
}
```

Use the `-asJob` parameter to run them as separate jobs, or run them in sequence for simplicity.  Remote PSSessions are another possiblilty to consider if you need to run multiple commands.  Research storing credentials, encrypted, in a file for repeated use.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not possible, you cannot log in to multiple accounts in command line. RDC is the only feasible way. May be you can automate the RDC for multiple users using other automation softwares like auto it, WSH scripting or some macro recorders. Which might help resolve some effort in your work.

Comment: thanks. any ideas on how or where to launch those automation scripts? i can get through one auto-logon user. can some startup script in that user's profile do that? any link to tutorials on those technologies you listed? a little more insight please...

Answer (score 0):

Use [runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx) to open new cmd. After that start your test, they will use your new credentials.

Comment: the `runas`-*ed* process will start with a different credentials, but will not get that user's desktop. neither that user's startup scripts will fire, nor will the startup processes execute. what is required is  to list that user in `Users` tab in task manager. as if that user has logged in from a Remote Desktop Conn. and closed the RD window without logging out.

Comment: His question does not mention these requirements, you can load profile of user using runas and run your scripts. Why do you need startup scripts

Comment: *...application needs a user session to run...* And setting up a session includes setting up the envirornment which in-turn includes startup scripts. Some of the tests might need snapshots, in which case again a dedicated console is required. RUNAS provides shared console. services provide no console. :(

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by 3rd party tool http://www.logonexpert.com via its command line tool, in such manner:

le.exe /logon user1 pass1 domain1

le.exe /logon user2 pass2 domain1